# Wildfly Security Subsystem: Migrating from Legacy to Elytron, security-domain not found

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, elytron

I am trying to migrate a project from using Legacy Security to using Elytron Security.

Until now (Legacy), all that was required for the authentication to work, was to create a Security Domain in Subsystems -> Security with the correct name ("*referencesApplicationDomain*").

My web.xml:

```
<web-app ..>
    ...
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>referencesApplicationDomain</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>anonymous</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            ....
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
...
</web-app>
```

My jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web ...>
    <deny-uncovered-http-methods>false</deny-uncovered-http-methods>
    <context-root>/references</context-root>
    <security-domain>referencesApplicationDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Of course our idea is to make our application work with Elytron only.

The problem is, however, I don't see where to create the security domain in Elytron.

I followed the [Wildfly Elytron Documentation](http://docs.wildfly.org/14/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#set-up-and-configure-authentication-for-applications) to create the security-domain as well as the http factory using jboss-cli.

When I check in jboss-cli, I see the security domain was created.

When I try to start the Wildfly server however, I get the following error:

```
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.security.security-domain.referencesApplicationDomain"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"references-war-1.0.11-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.BranchService.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.java:/jaas/referencesApplicationDomain]"
    ]
```

It seems like jboss is trying to find the security-domain in the old security subsystem instead of Elytron. But I don't understand why?

Small remark: I want to use the ApplicaationRealm, to use the users and groups inside the jboss configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that  is not needed with Elytron (in fact, it is for Legacy only). So the solution is just removing these from the xml files:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app ..>
    ...
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <!--<realm-name>referencesApplicationDomain</realm-name>-->
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

**jboss-web.xml:**

```
<jboss-web ...>
    <deny-uncovered-http-methods>false</deny-uncovered-http-methods>
    <context-root>/references</context-root>
    <!--<security-domain>referencesApplicationDomain</security-domain>-->
</jboss-web>
```

This works, because per default, the undertow system of Wildlfly is using ApplicationRealm as the default-security-domain.
You can verify that by looking at your standalone.xml.